# Facebook pixel constructor AdsPixel is not visible

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have downloaded the following below **Java code** from [Facebook developer website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/facebook-pixel-stats/v2.8) ***subsection Facebook Pixel Statistics***.

```
    APINodeList<AdsPixelStatsResult> adsPixelStatsResults = new AdsPixel(<PIXEL_ID>, context).getStats()
  .setAggregation(AdsPixelStatsResult.EnumAggregation.VALUE_CUSTOM_DATA_FIELD)
  .setEvent("product_info")
  .setStartTime(start_time)
  .setEndTime("1469739348")
  .execute();
```

When I pasted the code in my eclipse, I got this error `The constructor AdsPixel() is not visible`.

**Is this a bug or there is problem with my IDE ?**

Thanks..!

Comment: What does the notice right on top of that document say again …?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for that,

Where can I found the documents for v2.8, all the documentation on Facebook website is of old version

Comment: You are already looking at the documentation for v2.8 (notice how that URL you posted ends?)